# jQuery get "readyState" property of video

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, prop, readystate

As title,I cannot get DOM attrbute by `jQuery.attr()` But can get attrbute by `document.attrbute`. How to solve It?

```js
console.log($("#video01").attr('readyState'));
console.log($("#video01")[0].readyState);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id='video01'  src="http://cloud.video.taobao.com/play/u/2554695624/p/1/e/6/t/1/fv/102/28552077.mp4" autoplay=""></video>
```

Comment: Try `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) isn't attribute of element. It's property of document

Comment: `readyState` is not attribute but `property`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `prop` insted `attr`

```js
console.log($("#video01").prop('readyState'));
console.log($("#video01")[0].readyState);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id='video01'  src="http://cloud.video.taobao.com/play/u/2554695624/p/1/e/6/t/1/fv/102/28552077.mp4" autoplay=""></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

`readyState` is not an *attribute*. It is a *property*.
So, use

```
console.log($("#video01").prop('readyState'));
```

Comment: What difference about attribute and property?

Comment: _attribute_ is something that you see in your DOM tree, where as _property_ is not visible(or the property value you see in DOM may not be the exact property value). _Property_ changes dynamically, where as _Attributes_ don't( You can manipulate attributes by script, though ).

For example, `<input>` box has a _property_ called `value`, this value which change when you modify text inside it.

Answer (score -2):

Your code don't have "readyState"

---

```
console.log($("#video01").attr('readyState'));
```

---

readyState must be present on this tag

in above tag src,autoplay,id are attr